# how to mount synology without removing external hard drive in /mnt

Tags: mount, hard-drive, external-hdd, nfs, nas

I have 2 external HDD connected to my pc. I followed the [Synology instructions](https://kb.synology.com/tr-tr/DSM/tutorial/How_to_access_files_on_Synology_NAS_within_the_local_network_NFS) and ran the command `sudo mount -t nfs 196.168.x.x:/volumeX/test /mnt` this caused my currently connected external HDD to vanish. I had to reboot to get everything back to normal. How can I add the synology mount without removing my drives?

Comment: Use something else other than /mnt like /mnt/synology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mount command attaches a filesystem to a directory.  You can actually attach it at any directory and you should create one for it.  The `/mnt` directory is a frequent target of such mounts and is an empty directory created by default on most unix systems specifically for that purpose.  You can mount multiple things on /mnt, even at the same time, but if you do, only the last one will be visible until you umount it to expose the previous one.

However, it is probably best to use `/mnt` only for temporary manual mounts (and only one at a time) and not permanent ones.  I would recommend creating something like `/synology` or `/disks/synology` or something like that to make a family of directories you can target for semi-permanent mounts.

You could also either use `autofs` to automatically mount them on demand or add them to `/etc/fstab` to permanently mount them.

Comment: thanks for the good explanation, I appreciate it!